# What is the value of $f(100)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, contest-math, functional-equations

> We have $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^*$, a function that admits primitives and admits the relations $$\cos \left(f(x)\right)=1,\ ∀x\in \Bbb R, \quad\text{and}\quad|f(\pi )−\pi |≤\pi .$$
>
> What  is the value of $f(100)$?

**My thought.** We obviously have
$$\cos (f(100)) =1\overset{?}{\implies} f(100) =\arccos (1),$$
but this seems not to make any sense at all.

How can I use the provided inequality $|f(\pi)−\pi|≤\pi$?

Comment: By "the function admits primitives", do you mean the function is integrable?

Comment: What about the trivial

$$f(x)=2k\pi$$

$$|f(π)−π|≤π\implies k=0,1$$

Comment: @gimusi your function is defined on $\Bbb Z$ I presume .

Comment: @GuyFsone It is a constant function

Comment: @gimusi then your valuue of k should be fix beforehand not after

Comment: @GuyFsone I've made so to find the values which satisfy the inequality, then $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=2\pi$ are trivial solutions

Comment: @gimusi now I am confused. Does that bring a counterexample or a contradiction?

Comment: @GuyFsone maybe I'm loosing something about your OP

Comment: @PatrickStevens primitive means there is a function $g$ such that $g'=f$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because $f$ has a primitive $F$, then $f = F'$ has the intermediate value property. Note that $f(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \{2kπ \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}^*\}$ since $\cos(f(x)) \equiv 1$ and $f(x) \neq 0 \ (\forall x \in \mathbb{R})$, thus $f$ is a constant function. Also$$
|f(π) - π| \leqslant π \Longrightarrow 0 \leqslant f(π) \leqslant 2π,
$$
therefore$$
f(π) = 2π,
$$
which implies$$
f(x) \equiv 2π. \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
$$

Comment: So this had nothing  special to do 100  thanks

Answer (score 4):

Clearly $f(x)=2\pi k_x$ where $k_x\in\mathbb Z$ Besides
$$|2\pi k_x-\pi|\le\pi\iff-\pi\le2\pi k_x-\pi\le\pi\Rightarrow 0\le k_x\le1$$
Since $k_x$ is an integer the problem gives two solutions $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=2\pi$ but because of the function is from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^*$ the only solution is
$$f(x)=2\pi$$